# Update $in mongoDB nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a collection where I take only _id like this:

```
const query = {status: "init"};
const project = {_id:1};

db.collection("mycoll")
        .find(query)
        .project(project)
        .sort(sort)
        .limit(limit)
        .toArray(function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            update_coll(result);
            res.send(result);
        });
```

with console.dir(result)

```
[ { _id: ObjectID { _bsontype: 'ObjectID', id: [Object] } },
  { _id: ObjectID { _bsontype: 'ObjectID', id: [Object] } },
  { _id: ObjectID { _bsontype: 'ObjectID', id: [Object] } },
  { _id: ObjectID { _bsontype: 'ObjectID', id: [Object] } },
  { _id: ObjectID { _bsontype: 'ObjectID', id: [Object] } },
  { _id: ObjectID { _bsontype: 'ObjectID', id: [Object] } },
  { _id: ObjectID { _bsontype: 'ObjectID', id: [Object] } },
  { _id: ObjectID { _bsontype: 'ObjectID', id: [Object] } } ]
```

Now I'd like to do an single atomic update like this

```
db.collection("mycoll").update(
        {_id: {$in:[pending_array_whitelist]}},
        {
            $set: {
                status: "pending"
            }
        },
        {multi:true},
        (error, result) => {
            if (error) return console.log(error);
        }
    );
```

But My code doesn't work, I don't have any update.

If I do same query in shell, it works

Comment: remove `[]` from `$in`... Try this `{_id: {$in:pending_array_whitelist}}`

Comment: no, it doesn't work